# Проблема с postfix после обновления до ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

После обновления с ubuntu 15.10 до 16.04 перестал работать postfix

> postfix/proxymap[35158]: warning:
>   mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf is unavailable.
>   unsupported dictionary type: mysql
>
> postfix/cleanup[35159]: warning:
>   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error
>   for "user@domain.com"
>
> postfix/cleanup[35159]: warning: D79B580DBC: sender_bcc_maps map
>   lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later

в mail.err

> postfix/cleanup[35159]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
>   postfix/proxymap[35158]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql

postconf -m
pcre и mysql есть.

Переустановка postfix-mysql и postfix не помогают.

Comment: `mysql:/etc/...` — вроде бы, должна быть ещё приставка `proxy:`: `proxy:mysql:/etc/...`. // а mysqld работает? база данных, таблицы — присутствуют? // пакет postfix-pcre установлен?

Comment: mysqld работает - сайт на нем. postfix-pcre is already the newest version (3.1.0-3). В main.cf            sender_bcc_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf

Comment: вряд ли пакеты так криво собраны, чтобы вызывать подобные ошибки. возможно, не полностью или некорректно обновились. попробуйте переустановить всё, что связано с postfix. и в логи загляните — что postfix при запуске пишет. возможно, чем-то недоволен в конфигурации.

Comment: 'postfix/proxymap[3166]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: mysql                     
postfix/cleanup[3107]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "user@domain.ru"                     
postfix/cleanup[3107]: warning: D871180B43: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later                                  
postfix/pickup: warning: maildrop/1AAF98125E: error writing D871180B43: queue file write error'

Comment: В инете есть аналогичные проблемы и связаны с отсутствием postfix-mysql, postfix-pcre, решения основаны на их переустановке, но у меня эти компоненты уже есть и переустановка не помогает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил сам. Проблема была в неправильном пути к библиотекам в main.cf, которые видимо изменились после обновления до ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

После переезда с Debian 7.2 на Debian 9.4 и обновления ПО в новой версии Postfix обновлены пути до библиотек в файле `dynamicmaps.cf` :

/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf (Postfix 2.9.6-2):

```
# Postfix dynamic maps configuration file.
#
#type   location of .so file            open function   (mkmap func)
#====   ================================    =============   ============
tcp /usr/lib/postfix/dict_tcp.so        dict_tcp_open   
sqlite  /usr/lib/postfix/dict_sqlite.so     dict_sqlite_open    
mysql   /usr/lib/postfix/dict_mysql.so      dict_mysql_open 
pcre    /usr/lib/postfix/dict_pcre.so       dict_pcre_open
```

/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf (Postfix 3.1.8-0+deb9u1):

```
# Postfix dynamic maps configuration file.
#
#type   location of .so file            open function   (mkmap func)
#====   ================================    =============   ============
tcp /usr/lib/postfix/dict_tcp.so        dict_tcp_open   
sqlite  /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-sqlite.so      dict_sqlite_open    
mysql   /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-mysql.so       dict_mysql_open 
pcre    /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-pcre.so        dict_pcre_open
```

Аналог `dict_tcp.so` в `/usr/lib/postfix/` я не нашел.

После изменения путей и перезапуска Postfix письма из очереди стали отправляться.